# I have few images and I want to show it on iPad on the full screen?

Tags: ipad, uiimageview

I have few images and I want to show it on iPad on the full screen - with same images. and image sizes are not same. Is there way to Stretch images (UIImageView) programmatically

Thank you

Comment: sorry for mistake it's Stretch. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stretch an image within `UIImageView` you just need to set the appropriate contentMode.

You can set the UIImageView to be the size of the screen and set the content mode like follows

3 options

```
// assume iv is an UIImageView the size of screen
// First option stretches your image to the size of the screen
[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
// Second option scales your image without changing aspect ratio to the largest possible size such that the whole image fits
[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
// Third option scales your image without changing aspect ratio to the smallest possible size such that the screen is covered (potentially clipping some of your image)
[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```